# gnu makefile: shell function execution order in a recipe

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm using $(shell ...) gnu make function in a Makefile recipe, and it runs first before the preceding rows. Why?

A very simple example:

```
.PHONY: all
all:
    @echo 1
    @echo $(eval a=$(shell echo 2a 1>&2))2b
    @echo 3 $(a)
```

The output is:

```
2a
1
2b
3
```

First runs the $(shell ...) line (2a), then the other lines.
How can I manage to run the $(shell ...) function when its row runs in the recipe, in this order?

```
1
2a
2b
3
```

Edit:

Without $(shell ...) it works as I expected:

```
.PHONY: all
all:
    @echo 1
    $(eval a=a)
    @echo 2 $(a)
    $(eval a=b)
    @echo 3 $(a)
```

Output:

```
1
2 a
3 b
```

Edit 2:

Here is a part of the original Makefile. The pieces at >>> show the essence of my problem: I want to put the output of udisksctl into a make variable instead of file $@.loop (and do the same with $@.mount).

```
$(HDIMG): $(BOOTBLOCK_MBR_BIN) $(BOOTBLOCK_EXT2_BIN) $(LOADER_BIN) | $(DESTDIR)
        dd if=/dev/zero of=$@.ext2 bs=1 seek=$(PSIZEB) count=0 2>/dev/null
        $(MKFSEXT2) -F $@.ext2 >/dev/null
        dd if=$(word 2,$^) of=$@.ext2 conv=notrunc 2>/dev/null
        cp $< $@
        dd if=/dev/zero of=$@ bs=1 seek=$(HDSIZEB) count=0 2>/dev/null
        echo $(PFDISK) | $(TR) | $(FDISK) $@ >/dev/null
        dd if=$@.ext2 of=$@ bs=512 seek=$(PSTART) conv=sparse,notrunc iflag=fullblock 2>/dev/null
>>>     udisksctl loop-setup --file $@ --offset $(PSTARTB) --size $(PSIZEB) >$@.loop
        sed -i -e 's/.* //;s/\.//' $@.loop
        cat $@.loop
>>>     udisksctl mount --block-device $$(cat $@.loop) >$@.mount
        sed -i -e 's/.* //;s/\.//' $@.mount
        cat $@.mount
        #
        mkdir -p $$(cat $@.mount)/boot/
        cp $(word 2,$^) $$(cat $@.mount)/boot/
        #/sbin/filefrag -b512 -e /
        #
        udisksctl unmount --block-device $$(cat $@.loop)
        udisksctl loop-delete --block-device $$(cat $@.loop)
        rm $@.loop
```

Comment: Why do you want them in a _make_ variable?  Why can't they be in shell variables?

Comment: @MadScientist: I don't want to merge this many rows into one logical row. But if there is no better solution, I will do it.

Comment: It's quite possible that a script of this length should be put into a separate shell script rather than a make recipe.  However if you want to just avoid adding semicolons or backslashes, you can (assuming a suitably new version of GNU make) enable the `.ONESHELL` feature so that the entire recipe is passed to the same shell without needing semicolon/backslash.  See https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/One-Shell.html

Comment: @MadScientist Thanks for helping. I make a bash script, the makefile will be more clear. (I know about .ONESHELL and .SHELLFLAGS, but I don't want to use them, because I have more targets and recipes, more Makefiles that included into the main Makefile, and maybe this cause some other problem) I would accept your answer, but this is only a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `make` runs a recipe, it *first* expands all variables/functions in it, and *then* runs the shell commands line by line.

You can work around that by executing *every* shell command with `$(shell ...)`, or, in your case, by using `$(info ...)` instead of `echo`:

```
.PHONY: all
all:
    $(info 1)
    $(info $(eval a=$(shell echo 2a 1>&2))2b)
    $(info 3 $(a))
```

Output:

```
1
2a
2b
3
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
```

The `Nothing to be done for 'all'.` part is caused by the fact that after expanding the functions, the recipe is effectively empty (has 0 shell commands). Adding a no-op command (e.g. `@true`) to it removes the message.

Comment: "When make runs a recipe, it first expands all variables/functions in it, and then runs the shell commands line by line." Thanks for your reply. If I don't use $(shell ...) it works as I expected. I edit the original question with an example.

Comment: @LGabci Regarding the edit: Yes, why shouldn't it work? As I said, the first thing `make` does when executing a recipe is expading all variables/calling all functions in it. This turns `@echo 1 \n $(eval a=a) \n @echo 2 $(a) \n $(eval a=b) \n @echo 3 $(a)` into `@echo 1 \n @echo 2 a \n @echo 3 b`. Then it executes the resulting 3 shell commands.

Comment: The $(eval ...) is evalauted/executed in the order of rows in the recipe, but $(shell ...) is not? Or am I misunderstanding something? There is other workaround than using $(shell ...) for every shell command? My original problem was that one program made some small output, and I want that output to use for some other programs' input. I want to put that output into a make variable with $(shell ...) function, then use as command line paramater. Am I wrong?

Comment: All make variables and functions are expanded first.  That includes `shell` and `eval` and every other one as well.  In general it's an anti-pattern to use `shell` and `eval` inside recipes.  It should only be done in very complicated/obscure situations.  For all "standard" recipes you should be using shell variables and shell functions directly: a recipe is already running in a shell so there's no need for make's `$(shell ...)`.

Comment: @MadScientist: Thank you for your reply! I have read your super writing about GNU Make. It is amazing! "so there's no need for make's $(shell ...)" There is another way to put an output of a shell command into a make variable? Maybe I'm doing something completely wrong. I want to use a program's output for some other programs' input in a make recipe.

Comment: I said, no need _in a recipe_.  You would not normally set a make variable in a recipe.  You set make variables in the non-recipe parts of the makefile and set shell variables (if you need them) in a recipe.  To set a make variable to the output of a shell script you do indeed need to use `$(shell ...)`

Comment: @MadScientist: "You would not normally set a make variable in a recipe." Sorry I left out the "in a recipe" part, but I thought it is in the context. Normally I don't use eval or shell in recipes. But it is not a simple recipe, it creates a HDD image file (... eg. when I create a loop device in one line of the recipe I need to know on further lines which device it is: I can redirect it into a file, eg. $@.loopdev and use it on other lines as $$(cat $@.loopdev) or $$(< $@.loopdev), but that seems not elegant for me and uses an extra bash shell) Do you know a better solution?

Comment: The standard way is to use `;` and `\\` to continue the lines so they are run in the same shell, then use shell variables etc.  If you provide us with a more realistic situation we can give you better help.  The more abstract and far afield from your actual problem you make your question, the less we can provide helpful advice.

Comment: @MadScientist: thanks for the help. I'm going to edit the original question.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: You were right! I didn't understand at the first time. MadScientist helped me to understand. I accept your answer.

Comment: @MadScientist "The standard way is to use ; and \ to continue the lines so they are run in the same shell"

Wouldn't it be better to chain them using `&&` instead, to make sure the next command only runs if the preceding one was successful?

Comment: Sure. In the examples here, things like `echo 1` can't fail.  But if you have commands that might fail, and if you want to stop if they do, it's better to use `&&`.